# Problem after updating Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2.2.0

After updating Magento to 2.2.0 with command line I got the following errors and then a whole list of files: How to fix?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): 
Element 'page': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 806


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): 
Element 'page': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 806

#0 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/cosmotol/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<!--\r\n    <refe...')
#8 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#9 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#10 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#11 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#12 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#13 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#15 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#16 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#17 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#18 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#20 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#22 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#33 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /home/cosmotol/domains/cosmotology.nl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a consequence of the validation working as expected in Magento 2.2, which it didn't in earlier versions.** Refer to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116) or [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11194).

The solution is to find the xml that is not following the definition. Often, this is a plugin, and a simple solution could be to update them to the latest available version.

To allow a better answer, please post more of the exception log.

Comment: I've pasted more of the exception log now. I don't know where to look for the problem.

Comment: Which version of ultimo do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You should search all XML layout files for "**page**" nodes in the layout folder for all extensions you have:

> `/app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/layout/`

And search all `layout` folders in your theme module overrides:

> `/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/{module}/layout/`

You should be looking for a "page" node which isn't properly opened and closed.

A proper example is:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
...
</page>
```

Most probably there's a typo in one of the files, for example a missing opening or closing "<", ">" or "/", like this:

```
page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```